# How to get difference between 2 dates as duration via using xpath on BPM 11g

Tags: xpath, oracle11g, business-process-management

Need to get difference between 2 dateTime payload objects as duration format for using on HT expiration value. (i.e. returned as PT2055M or P1DT10H15M) 
Actually checked functions on that link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/dev.1111/e10224/bp_appx_functs.htm#autoId13
And i tried to solve the issue by creating duration such as

> `concat("P", xp20:year-from-dateTime(string(bpmn:getDataObject('myPayloadDate'))) - xp20:year-from-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime()) ,"Y", xp20:month-from-dateTime(string(bpmn:getDataObject('myPayloadDate'))) - xp20:month-from-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime()),"M", xp20:day-from-dateTime(string(bpmn:getDataObject('myPayloadDate'))) - xp20:day-from-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime()),"DT", xp20:hour-from-dateTime(string(bpmn:getDataObject('myPayloadDate'))) - xp20:hour-from-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime()),"H",xp20:minute-from-dateTime(string(bpmn:getDataObject('myPayloadDate'))) - xp20:minute-from-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime()),"M")`

But realized that this approach interests with just only seperate values not whole values as expected.
I could not find the right composition of functions to solve.
Could you plz guide?

Comment: Please include all relevant information  within your question, not external links. Also, what have you tried so far? Please improve the question to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an XPath 2.0 processor, just use the subtraction operator. For example

```
current-date() - xs:date('2001-03-04')
```

gives

```
P4744D
```

(You said "dates" but your examples look more like dateTime's. The subtraction operator will work with either.)

Comment: Thank you sir. Suppose that XPath version on BPM11g is 2.0. Because checked it that if running current-date(), then see it runs without error. But when i assign this expression regarding to you shared infos xp20:add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime(xp20:current-dateTime(),"PT1D")-xp20:current-dateTime() to inteval or string element. After run fields obtain NaN value. What might be problem

Comment: The Oracle spec says "In addition to the standard XPath 1.0 functions, the XSLT Mapper provides many prebuilt extension functions and can support user-defined functions and named templates. The extension functions are prefixed with oraext or orcl and mimic XPath 2.0 functions.". So it looks like it's not real XPath 2.0, which means you'll have to read the manual.